# Android ExpandableListView how to save expanded/collapsed state?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom 3-level expandable list view. Done it with 2 adapters, which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`: `ParentAdapter` and `ChildAdapter`.

Inside `getChildView` of `ParentAdapter` I just summon `ChildAdapter`.

**But when I expand the 3rd level and scroll it out of view, it restores itself back to collapsed state.**

How can I fix this?

I guess, I have to save expanded/collapsed state for my `getGroupView` inside ChildAdapter, but I don't know how to correctly implement this.

Or should I save state for `getChildView` inside ParentAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like, I've done it.

First, add inside add additional parameter `isExpanded` inside your item.

In `ParentAdapter` inside `getChildView` add condition:

```
  //expand child if was previously expanded
  if (item.isExpanded)
  {
    expandableListView.expandGroup(childPosition);
  }
```

In `ChildAdapter` inside `getChildView` add this:

```
    if (item.isExpanded)
   {
     expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
     expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

This will save an expanded/collapsed state of your items and change them correctly.

At least, this implementation solved my issue, although, a better solution could exist.